# select multiple checkbox in gridview in asp.net not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code to select multiple checkbox in `GridView` in `asp.net` but it is not working

```
protected void cbheader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        ((CheckBox)gridViewRow.FindControl("chkcol"))
               .Checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it is a nonsense to do a postback (generating traffic) only to check few checkboxes...
IMHO it is better to use javascript.

Here there are some examples: [multiple checkboxes inside a GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11207/Selecting-multiple-checkboxes-inside-a-GridView-co)q [using jquery](http://www.mostefaiamine.com/post/2013/11/02/ASPNET-GridView-Multi-Select-Using-CheckBoxes-and-JQuery), [checkbox as template column](http://bprateek.blogspot.com/2009/08/javascript-to-select-one-checkbox-at.html) and [last one](http://weblogs.asp.net/farazshahkhan/archive/2008/08/02/mutually-exclusive-checkbox-in-gridview-using-javascript.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript to check all checkboxes in DataGrid. Postback requests is not a good idea to solve this. There is a good example of how to implement such functionality using JavaScript:
[Implement check all checkbox functionality in ASP.Net GridView control using JavaScript](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-check-all-checkbox-functionality-in-ASPNet-GridView-control-using-JavaScript.aspx)