# selecting rows in gridview in asp.net through Shift key (Selecting multiple rows from one to many using shift)

Tags: javascript, c#, gridview

How to select group of rows through shift keys in javascript. For example, I have a ASP.NET Grid View that has few rows. When I click on a row and then press shift key and then click on another row, how to select the rows in between these first row selected and the latest row clicked.

I need to implement this in Javascript. I have a gridview that contains some of the columsn which are hidden and not displayed in the UI columns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772763/select-multiple-checkbox-in-gridview-in-asp-net-not-working

Comment: @jasonscript: Ok one off topic, are you from India? Well I do not have a checkbox in my grid. I just select rows without checkbox just by clicking on row. Please help?